# Android Design/Architecture: Static Reference vs Service

Tags: android

Suppose I have a RecyclerView in my activity A. This RecyclerView is dynamic, and it is updated whenever there's new information (will explain more). Upon clicking an item, it takes me to another activity B. So, suppose there is new information for Activity A. I receive this information via a (Parse) notification.

While on Activity B, what means should I be using to update the RecyclerView on Activity A, assuming I want to keep it active all the time?

Currently, I have static references to the adapter, and I update the updater using this static reference from Activity B. But I feel this is not a good design/approach as static references shouldn't be used unless extremely necessary (right?). For instance, is a Service/ServiceIntent more useful/a better approach in this case?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Currently, I have static references to the adapter" Currently you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Budius Can you recommend a better approach?

Comment: try using event bus (otto or GreenRobot)

Comment: @TJ56 this talk explain it in great lenght https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE the quick version is: you need a local storage to receive these data that later can be quickly read by any element that needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Static Reference vs Service

Aside from comparing apples with bananas, you are doing this wrong with static reference, leading to memory leak (try using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)...). You should  use EventBus (like [GreenRobot's](http://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/), [OTTO](http://square.github.io/otto/)) to distribute data to various components of your application.

Comment: I understand. I will give EventBus a try now; thank you!

Comment: Exactly what I just wanted to answer. Event bus is great and it has multiple advantages, from being thread safe, to being able to overload the onEvent method, and having 4 onEvent methods for controlling on which thread to execute the callback (onEvent, onEventMainThread, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping static reference of adapter you can use the singleton class which maintain your data information. So from **Activity B** you can update the singleton class and in **Activity A** onResume method you can update or refresh your recycle view. Singleton classes will not cause memory leak unless you keeping static reference to then in any activity  [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736131/activity-holding-reference-to-singleton-leaks-memory)

Answer (score 0):

you can use interface callback to update your adapter. 
1.define a public interface in ActivityB 
2.define a static instance of interface and a static method to init instance in ActiivtyB.
3. call the static instance init method in ActivityA oncreate and implement your code in interface method.
4.update your adapter in ActivityB by call instance.method.